# tex4ebook and 4ht files

Tags: tex4ht, lua, tex4ebook

I am using MiKTeX on windows and calling `tex4ebook.lua` as a parameter to `lualatex` to make epub3.

Can somebody explain in simple terms what the `.4ht` files in the `tex4ebook` directory are used for Likewise `exec_epub3.lua`?  If one were to modify, how to use them to generate custom ebook output?

Comment: The .4ht files are special configuration files used by tex4ht. For each .sty files if some configuration required is written on corresponding .4ht files. When  an epub3 file is generated, `tex4ebook` first executes `exec_epub.lua` and later executes `exec_epub3.lua`. The `exec_epub3.lua` generates a TOC if it is not generated and cleans the content.opf file generated by `exec_epub.lua`. So if you need to adjust anything then it should be done using a custom config file (.cfg), `exec_epub.lua` and `exec_epub3.lua` as required.

Comment: Thanks much, I thought so but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tex4ebook` compilation process is following:

- `tex4ebook` is `Lua` script, which is called using `texlua`, interpreter distributed with `TeX` distributions. It prepares compilation parameters and load compilation module for specified output format. Each module has functions for preparing, executing and finalizing the compilation.
- basic output module is `exec_epub.lua`, other modules uses it in the background and add some stuff needed for their formats.
- `make4ht` is used to execute all necessary applications (most notably `latex`, `tex4ht` and `t4ht`. user can specify custom [build file](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#build-files) and select additional apps like `bibtex` or `makeindex`)
- `latex` is called with special configuration, `tex4ht.sty`, `tex4ebook.sty` and `tex4ebook.4ht` are automatically loaded. In case of `epub3`, `tex4ebook-epub3.4ht` is loaded as well. `tex4ebook.4ht` is used mainly to create `epub` metadata, like the `NCX` and `OPF` files.

If you want to modify the `tex4ebook` behavior, it is best to use a [custom configuration file](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial#configurations)

Comment: If I write a custom configuration file, I'd like to start from a default configuration file. Where can I find it, if there is any?

Comment: @mmj the default configuration for `HTML` output is provided in `html4.4ht file`. It is generated file without comments, so it is not easily understandable. [There is the documented source](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-html4.html)